# Could I have better asked about a language's lack of an important feature?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions, opinion-based

I asked [a question about immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966084/guaranteeing-immutability-in-c-sharp) that was closed as "opinion-based". I respect the closers' judgement, but I don't completely agree. I'd like to know what I'm missing and how I could have asked it more usefully.

I think someone might think the question was opinion based like:

- Isn't immutability totally awesome?
- I drafted a proposal for a C# revision in 5 minutes, and I think it's really cool, don't you agree?

I totally didin't mean that. The question was, assuming that immutability is useful and desirable in some scenarios, and that we usually as programers prefer to have common patterns enforced by the compiler to avoid headaches, is there any technical reason for not baking immutable types into the language itself?

I think it's an objective question with possible objective answers like:

- It is not possible for technical reasons A, B, C....
- It is possible and they are working on it (someone answered this in the comments).
- Microsoft doesn't think it's that useful, so it's probably not gonna happen (ideally with sources) (note that even if this anwer states an opinion, the answer itself is objective).

Possible opinion based answers would be like:

- Immutability is/isn't that useful!
- Your design is totally cool/wrong!

I think the problem with this anwers are the answers themselves missing the point of the question, appart from being totally opinion based, so this answers should be downvoted/flagged, not the question itself.

So, to sum up, was my question closed because:

- Due to poor wording or lack of clearance it was misunderstood?
- Even if it is objective, it's probably going to cause opinion based answers and noise?
- Some other reason I might be missing?

(As a side note, I found really interesting ideas about all of this in a series of blog posts by Eric Lippert starting with [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/))

Comment: "Why did the designers of language X not do Y" type questions tend to get closed as opinion based because most of the time, there is no way to provide a useful, non-subjective answer. I don't know anything about C# but seeing as Marc Gravell himself found your question valuable enough to post an answer, I've blindly cast a reopen vote. Maybe others will agree.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really intended to be used to fulfil a curiosity, it is intended to be a repository for common programming problems with their solutions. That's a gross generalisation as there is a broader spectrum of questions that are perfectly on-topic, but a question which boils down to "why did somebody I don't know the name of do or did not implement bla" is not a good question. The better question would be: how in language X might I achieve whatever goal I want to achieve, in this case immutability. That is results oriented, not curiosity oriented. Search first, of course.

Comment: Might be worth asking in the https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ chat room if they want that question, could work there I think.

Comment: @Mat this question is a  poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is at SO. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Yes of course...

Comment: @Gimby I completely disagree. It definitely *is* a useful question. There may be solid reasons that a feature isn't supported, and why that feature is a bad idea in the language. Answers may also include methods to implement a pattern properly in a particular language. While some parts may rely on the original designers to answer (however - C# is very good in this aspect; some answers come directly from the source, so this isn't necessarily an issue), technical reasons can be answered by anyone.

Comment: @Rob Hey, you're very free to have your own opinion. I have my own too. When it comes to Stack Overflow, I choose to care less about what I personally think, it makes the process of using the site far less dramatic.

Comment: @Rob: "*There may be solid reasons that a feature isn't supported, and why that feature is a bad idea in the language.*" And there *may not* be such a reason. That's why these questions ought to be off-topic; you cannot know when asking if there is an objective reason or not.

Comment: "I drafted a proposal for a C# revision in 5 minutes"... I strongly suspect that just listing all *other* features that could be impacted by proposal would take longer. Consider checking out  [Minus 100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/) in addition to Eric's answer on the duplicate...

Comment: @NicolBolas By the same logic, all questions ought to be off-topic, because it's possible there's no solution. But more seriously; these questions will *always* have an answer. The main problem stems from the fact that the people with the answer may not be users of this site. The answer doesn't even need to contain a good *reason* for the decision. [Here's a perfectly good example of such a question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899347/563532). The answer here is essentially 'Why just picked one way to do it'. Perfectly good question in my eyes.

Comment: "Why not?" questions are almost always poor questions because they all have the same answer: **The design team is not required to give a reason for not implementing a feature**. Rather, the people who want a feature are required to make the case that the feature would be **the best possible use of the design team's time, the implementation team's time, the test team's time, and so on**.  You want this feature? Great. It's an awesome feature. The design team has considered it **many times** and always concluded that there was a *better* feature to spend effort on.

Comment: So rather than asking "why did you foolish people not implement my obviously awesome feature fifteen years ago?", spend your valuable time *advocating for the feature on the github forum*. Join the discussion. Write a prototype. "Why not?" questions are not helpful.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input, I now can understand why these kind of questions are controversial and usually not useful (not necessarily opinion based though). @Eric Lippert I wish I had enough knowledge to get involved like that, I certainly would enjoy the discussions. The question was not in that tone, it was more like I'm sure there's a really good reason for this, and I would like to understand it. I also read a blog post (I think it was yours) about how the tiniest feature involves a lot of time in implementing, testing, documenting, translating, releasing... A good reason by itself.